# Having problems with uploading photo with PHP

Tags: php, image-uploading

I am trying to upload some picture to my file called "uploads"
the problem is that it keeps saying :".Sorry, there was an error uploading your file." My "uploads" file is located in "/Users/Ony/Documents/uploads/".

This is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and this my php code:

```
    <?php
$target_dir = "/Users/Ony/Documents/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;

echo($target_dir);

$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

even my php.ini should be ok, because it is set like this

```
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads = On

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20
```

Thank you.

Comment: this is my  PHP Version => 5.5.27

Comment: Are you working on ubuntu or windows?

Comment: If working on ubuntu/linux then it may be the problem of permission to the folder.

Comment: I am working with mac osx

Comment: Please take a look on this link regarding permission. May be this can help. https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18894?locale=en_US

Comment: That's it! Thank you :)

Comment: Glad to help. Happy coding.

Comment: Omg I have checked my code so many times :/ :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please verify if `uploads` directory has `write` permission assigned to it.